Can affirming infinite dependency relationships imply asserting it's independence?
If I take as a brute fact that a thing O1 existentially depends on another thing O2 that underpins it, and this in turn depends on O3, and so on ad infinitum (without delving into the types of dependency that may exist, i.e., constitutive, causal, functional...), can I say that the fact that things are dependent all the way down implies the independence of this fact? Would be this a 'fact'?
That is to say, can I say that asserting that 'everything is dependent' is an independent fact in itself?
If so, what kind of affirmation would be this?

"Everything" is not well defined in your question. And should you want to then go ahead and define "everything", be warned that it gets tricky.

Okay, what if I say 'the set of all dependency relations'? Could it also be stated as an invariant of all dependency relations?  @JonathanZ

"The fact... implies the independence of this fact"??? A fact implies its own independence? Independence of what and in what sense of "independence"? I am afraid you'll have to delve into the meaning of dependence to make the intended question sensible. I doubt that it is if the same sense of "dependence" is used throughout.

@Conifold Thank you. I'm thinking about how to rephrase it more precisely. I thought the meaning would be clear, but I see that it’s not. The only thing I want to say is that if 'each thing depends upon other thing = x,' then 'x is independent'.

Does the infinite dependency relation within a Fibonacci sequence means its complete independence?...

Could start by clarifying 'Can affirming infinite dependency relationships imply asserting it's independence?' That doesn't work in basic English, which suggests any discussion first needs to define its terms…
